# Difference between" npm run serve" and "npm run dev" in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

What is the difference between `npm run serve` and `npm run dev` in vuejs. Why should i use npm run serve command to run the project

Comment: Look at your `package.json` file. The difference is whatever is defined in that file. It's different for everyone.

Comment: Refer vue CLI 3, You can find command And also you can use Vue GUI if you want an easy path.

Answer (score 65):

`npm run serve` basically is just saying "[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) please **run** the command I defined under the name **serve** in **package.json**" the same happens with `npm run dev`.

Given this the commands can do the exact same thing, similar things, or very different things. Usually they are a shorthand for running a dev server on localhost, but it’s not a rule, only a convention.

So you'll need to check in your `package.json` file and look for

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "[list of commands here]",
    "dev": "[list of commands here]"
},
```

Comment: short and well explained, finger up my friend